# Defining cookie as secure and httponly in web config (Classic ASP, IIS 6.0).

Tags: iis, asp-classic, session-cookies, secure-coding, cookie-httponly

I need to declare all ASP cookies as secure and `httponly`. The code is in Classic ASP and `IIS ver is 6.0`.

The cookie has been defined as follows:

```
<sessionState
mode="InProc"
stateConnectionString=""
sqlConnectionString=""
cookieless="false"
timeout="20"
/>
```

Is there a way in which I can change the properties of the cookies created by the application?

Answer (score 0):

that is not possible for classic asp. furthermore you are showing code of the web.config, right? taht file has absolutely nothing to do with classic asp...